# Calculate percentage of nested aggregation per bucket

Tags: elasticsearch

How can I get a parent aggregation to calculate the percentage of a particular term in the nested aggregation per parent aggregation?

For example, suppose I have the following data:

- January (100 sales)

  - type: t-shirt(10 sales),I need: 10/100 = .10)
  - type: pants(50 sales), I need: 50/100 = .50)
  - type: skirt(40 sales), I need: 40/100 = .40)
- February (60 sales)

  - type: t-shirt(58 sales); I need: 58/60 = .96)
  - type: pants(1 sales); I need: 1 / 60 = .016)
  - type: skirt(1 sales); I need: 1 / 60 = .016)

The result I need is:

- January:

  - t-shirt: 10%
  - pants: 50%
  - skirt: 40%
- February:

  - t-shirt: 96%
  - pants: 1.6%
  - skirt: 1.6%

For example, based on elasticsearch official exemple it would be something like this:

```
POST /sales/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "sales_per_month": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "date",
        "interval": "month"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "types": {
          "term": {
            "field": "type"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But then I don't know how to get calculate those percentages.